# Методология БЭМ: можно ли ЭЛЕМЕНТАМ блока наследовать свойства, или всегда нужно копировать одинаковые свойства для КАЖДОГО елемента блока?

Tags: html, css, бэм, методология

Здравствуйте! Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с методологией БЭМ на примере. Есть HTML:

```
<div class="block">
    <p class="block__paragraph">Some text</p>
    <span class="block__fragment">Some fragment</span>
</div>
```

Нужно стилизовать селекторы **block__paragraph** и **block__fragment** блока block. В дизайне оба селектора имеют одинаковый цвет и подчеркивание.

**Вариант 1:**

```
.block {
 color: red;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
```

В результате элементы block__paragraph и block__fragment УНАСЛЕДУЮТ color и  text-decoration. Нужно понимать, что так как они ЭЛЕМЕНТЫ, то НЕ БУДУТ использоваться вне блока.

**Вариант 2:**

```
.block__paragraph {
 color: red;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

.block__fragment {
 color: red;
 text-decoration: underline;
 }
```

Здесь мы просто копируем одинаковые свойства КАЖДОМУ элементу (много одинакового кода).

Скажите пожалуйста, какой вариант по методологии БЭМ верный? Может есть ссылка на ту часть документации, которая дает ответ на вопрос.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Я просто поделюсь своим пониманием БЭМ безо всяких ссылок. Поэтому всё нижеописанное моё личное мнение.

Основная идея БЭМ в переиспользуемости компонента и в том что его можно было бы легко менять, а наследование в данном случае мне видится чем-то неявным (потому что вы привязываетесь к тому что один элемент лежит в другом) и противоречащим тому, чтобы мы могли разнести без проблем элементы в разные контейнеры (в пределах БЭМ Блока) и они бы друг от друга не зависели (насколько это возможно).

Ещё дублирования в любом виде — это почти всегда плохо, поэтому я бы просто общие фрагменты выносил в один селектор:

```
.block__paragraph,
.block__fragment {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```